# Script break when variable is used

Tags: shell-script

**script01.sh** works just fine

```
#!/bin/sh -x
egrep 'snmp.* version [123]|ip route ' $1
```

output

```
[user@linux ~]$ script01.sh file.txt
+ egrep 'snmp.* version [123]|ip route ' file.txt
```

However, when I changed the content and put it in variable, it's break.

**script02.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh -x
var='snmp.* version [123]|ip route '
egrep $var $1
```

**output script02.sh**

```
[user@linux ~]$ script02.sh file.txt
' x='snmp.* version [123]|ip route
+ egrep 'snmp.*' version '[123]|ip' route $'\r' file.txt
egrep: version: No such file or directory
egrep: [123]|ip: No such file or directory
egrep: route: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
```

When I double quoted both `$var` & `$1`, this is happen.

**script03**

```
#!/bin/sh -x
var='snmp.* version [123]|ip route '
egrep "$var" "$1"
```

**output script03**

```
[user@linux ~]$ script03.sh file.txt
' var='snmp.* version [123]|ip route
' file.txt
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Your `$var` and `$1` needs to be quoted

Comment: Thanks @Inian, I did double quoted it as script03.sh (updated, see above) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script breaks because you are using `$var` unquoted on the command line with `egrep`.  This causes the shell to split it into separate words on spaces, tabs and newlines (by default), and each word is also undergoing filename globbing (e.g. `snmp.*` would be expanded to all matching filenames in the current directory) before `egrep` is called with the generated words.

Since `egrep` would only recognise the *first* non-option argument as a pattern, the remaining arguments are assumed to be filenames.

Instead, do

```sh
#!/bin/sh -x
pattern='snmp.* version [123]|ip route '
grep -E -n --color=auto -e "$pattern" "$1"
```

`grep -E` is the same as `egrep` and since we put the pattern to match in a variable, I'd like to explicitly tell `grep` that one of the arguments is the pattern with `-e`.  Apart from that, I'm double quoting all variable expansions to avoid the above mentioned word splitting and globbing that the shell would otherwise do on the variables' values (note that `$1` would also be affected by this).

Your script also appears to have at least some lines ending with `\r` (carriage return), as if they were DOS text lines.  This could happen if you are writing your script with a Windows text editor.  To convert your script to a Unix text file, use `dos2unix` on the script file.

See also

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

---

With a small modification, you script could be made to work on multiple files given on the command line:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -x

pattern='snmp.* version [123]|ip route '

for pathname do
    grep -E -n --color=auto -e "$pattern" "$pathname"
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda, I did double quoted it as script03.sh (updated, see above) but it didn't work.

Comment: @user11392987 I was just about to add that your script may well be a DOS text file. This may happen if you wrote the script on a Windows machine. You may want to convert it to a Unix text file using the `dos2unix` utility.

Comment: Thnaks @Kusalananda, yeah that was the root cause. It works after I convert it with `dos2unix`